# Type of 'title' has different optionality than required by protocol 'UIPreviewActionItem'

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

So I'm trying to create a couple of preview action items in swift for a view controller like this:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)

override internal func previewActionItems() -> [UIPreviewActionItem] {

    let cancelAction = UIPreviewAction(title: "Cancel Appointment", style: .Destructive) { (action, previewViewController) -> Void in
        print("Cancel Appointment")
    }

    return [cancelAction]
}
```

Which gives me this compile error message:

```
Type of 'title' has different optionality than required by protocol 'UIPreviewActionItem'.
```

I understand the error message, but how am I supposed to change the optionality of 'title'?

The same code in Objective-C works perfectly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, works fine in my playground.

Comment: I am guessing that `UIPreviewAction` implements `UIPreviewActionItem` protocol. And the `UIPreviewAction` has a `title` property required by the protocol, but it is an optional and it should be not. Or the other way around.

Comment: Make sure you don't have syntax errors that would confuse compiler.

Comment: Some more infos: start a single view application and add nothing but the code mentioned above: same error. So I can rule out syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that reading the documentation is kind of important:

```
IMPORTANT
```

Do not adopt this protocol in custom classes.

I had my custom view controller adopt to the protocol:

```
extension CustomViewController: UIPreviewActionItem {
```

}

should be changed to

```
extension CustomViewController {
```

}